# Extracting an array of values from an array of hashes in Puppet

Tags: arrays, hash, puppet, hiera

I have the following array of hashes in hiera:

```
corporate_roles:
  - name: 'user.1'
    system_administrator: true
    global_administrator: false
    password: TestPassword1234
  - name: 'user.2'
    system_administrator: true
    global_administrator: true
    password: TestPassword1234
```

I need to extract a list of users with a give role (eg `global_administrator`) to be assigned later on.
I managed to use the `map` function to extract the data I need:

```
$corporate_roles = lookup('corporate_roles')
$global_admins = $corporate_roles.map | $hash | { if ($hash['global']){$hash['name']}}
notify { "global admins are: ${global_admins}":
  }
```

However this results in `undef` values seemingly making their way into the array for the users that don't match the criteria:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/salesraft_test/Notify[global admins are: [, user.2]]/message: defined 'message' as 'global admins are: [, user.2]'
       Notice: Applied catalog in 0.04 seconds
```

I can get around this by using the `filter` function as such:

```
$test = $global_admins.filter | $users | {$users =~ NotUndef}
```

Which results in clean output:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/salesraft_test/Notify[global admins are: [user.2]]/message: defined 'message' as 'global admins are: [user.2]'
       Notice: Applied catalog in 0.03 seconds
```

But I suspect there must be a better way of doing this and I am either missing some logic in my `map` or I am likely using the wrong function altogether for this.

I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I suspect there must be a better way of doing this and I am either
> missing some logic in my map or I am likely using the wrong function
> altogether for this.

`map()` emits exactly one output item for each input item, so if your objective is to apply a single function to obtain your wanted output from your (lengthier) input, then indeed, `map` will not achieve that.

> I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Personally, I would do the job by `filter`ing out the hashes you want from your input and then `map`ping those  to the wanted output form (as opposed to `map`ping and then `filter`ing the result):

```
$global_admins = $corporate_roles.filter |$hash| {
    $hash['global_administrator']
  }.map |$hash| { $hash['name'] }
```

I like that because it's nice and clear, but if you want to do it with one function call instead of two then you're probably looking for [`reduce`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.17/function.html#reduce):

```
$global_admins = $corporate_roles.reduce([]) |$admins, $hash| {
  $hash['global_admin'] ? {
    true    => $admins << $hash['name'],
    default => $admins
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and made things much more legible. Thank you.